# Issue with NSSortDiscriptors

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I am making an iPhone App and when I run it after around 8 seconds it crashes and displays this message:

```
-[__NSArrayI sortUsingDescriptors:]: CRASH 
-[__NSArrayI sortUsingDescriptors:]: STACK TRACE 
 (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b6a5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027968b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02c07903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02b5a90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02b5a4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Floadt                              0x0003ebaa -[StreamViewController sortArrayBasedOndate] + 490
    6   Floadt                              0x0003cdb6 -[StreamViewController updateArraysWithSort] + 246
    7   Floadt                              0x0003e969 -[StreamViewController refetchTimeline] + 73
    8   Floadt                              0x0003efec -[StreamViewController timerRefresh:] + 92
    9   Foundation                          0x011d7927 __NSFireTimer + 97
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x02b28bd6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x02b285bd __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1181
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x02b10628 __CFRunLoopRun + 1816
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02b0fac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x02b0f8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0452f9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x0452f809 GSEventRun + 104
    17  UIKit                               0x01929d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    18  Floadt                              0x00063f3d main + 141
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x037be70d start + 1
```

Basically Im trying to organize both of the objects in two separate arrays in the same Array, here is the code that I am currently using:

```
  NSDateFormatter *fmtDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [fmtDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDateFormatter *fmtTime = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmtTime setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"start_date" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    // Instagram Date Retrieval
    NSDictionary *instagram = self.instaPics;
    NSString *createdAt = instagram[@"created_time"];
    int createdAtN = [createdAt intValue];
    NSTimeInterval timestamp = (NSTimeInterval)createdAtN;
    NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];

    // Twitter Date Retrieval
    NSDictionary *twitter = self.tweets;
    NSString *twitterCreated = twitter[@"created_at"];
    int createdAtTwitter = [twitterCreated intValue];
    NSTimeInterval timestampTwitter = (NSTimeInterval)createdAtTwitter;
    NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestampTwitter];

    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter];

[totalFeed sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: Update your question with the complete error message about the unrecognized selector.

Comment: Why doesn't your comparator make use of the two `obj` parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Your sort code does not make sense to me. You are creating a sort descriptor using an NSComparator block.

When you write a comparator block, you provide a block of code that takes 2 objects as input (obj1 and obj2 is the normal naming, and your comparator follows that model)

You are supposed to write code that compares these 2 objects and returns an NSComparisonResult based on which object should be placed first in the sort.

Your block does not do anything with obj1 and obj2.

Instead, you are attempting to look at the contents of instaPics and tweets properties of the owning object. That makes no sense in an NSComparator block.

I don't know why your code is crashing. The crash log makes it look like you've got a zombie, since I see a doesNotRecognizeSelector message. What is the error message (not the stack trace, the error message) that's shown when it crashes?

Comment: This is really a long comment, not an actual answer to the question.

Comment: a zombie would cause a bad access, doesNotRecognizeSelector means that a method was called on an object that does not implement that method

Comment: I have changed it so that i use the two objects instead of creating them but nothing changed.